# Comparing the characters of a selected item on a spinner with a set of characters

Tags: android, android-studio, character, android-spinner

I'm trying to compare the characters of a selected item on a spinner with another character. I'm defending my final year project tomorrow 29/07/2016 and I'm still not through with my coding.

```
 public void addListenerToSelect_PHS(){
     Select_DayOfTheWeek = (Spinner)
         findViewById(R.id.DayOfTheWeek);
     Select_DayOfTheWeek.setOnItemSelectedListener(newAdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
     @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String itemSelectedInSpinner = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (itemSelectedInSpinner .equals("Computer Science")){
                Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "You are from Computer Science", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Select_DayOfTheWeek = (Spinner)
                        findViewById(R.id.DayOfTheWeek);
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> Select_DayOfTheWeekAdapter =
                        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),R.array.ComptWeek,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                Select_DayOfTheWeekAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                Select_DayOfTheWeek.setAdapter(Select_DayOfTheWeekAdapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: (Marking for future editing to remove deadlines. It is extremely unusual for me to leave this in, but I will make a rare exception. Please do try to garner help from other avenues as well - it is not sensible to rely on volunteer sources if you absolutely need to be done today. Good luck).

Answer (score 1):

```
String selectedItem=Select_DayOfTheWeek.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(selectedItem.equals("Computer Science")){
 Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "You are from Computer Science", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: @halfer...Thanks a million. In Yoruba...Ese pupo.